# Oracle Plsql : How to complete execution of a procedure without waiting for its subprogram to complete

Tags: oracle, plsql

In Oracle PlSql, I'm calling my stored procedure after performing some action on screen.
After execution of some piece of code I want to insert some records into a table but insert should happen after 20 mins. I want to run insert job/procedure independently so that my main procedure completes its execution.

Any sort of help would be appreciated !!

Comment: Have a look at DBMS_SCHEDULER

Comment: Any specific reason for executing subprogram after 20 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this below snippet helps.

```
--Table to create dummy insertion
CREATE TABLE TEST_SO_TAB
(
COL1 NUMBER
);


--Procedure to replicate scenario
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE TEST_SO_SCHEDULER(
    p_in IN NUMBER)
AS
  lv sys.odcinumberlist;
BEGIN
  SELECT LEVEL BULK COLLECT INTO lv FROM dual CONNECT BY level < 100;
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job ( job_name => 'DELTA_REFRESH_JOB', 
                              job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK', 
                              job_action => 'DECLARE                        
                                            lv1 sys.odcinumberlist;                      
                                            BEGIN                        
                                            SELECT LEVEL BULK COLLECT INTO lv1 FROM dual CONNECT BY level < 100;                        
                                            IF lv1.EXISTS(1) THEN                          
                                            FORALL i IN lv1.FIRST..lv1.LAST                          
                                            INSERT INTO TEST_SO_TAB VALUES                            
                                            ( lv1(i)                            
                                            );                        
                                            END IF;                      
                                            END', 
                            start_date => SYSTIMESTAMP+ INTERVAL '20' MINUTE, 
                            end_date => NULL, 
                            enabled => TRUE, 
comments => 'Job defined entirely by the CREATE JOB procedure.');
END;
/
```